# Django URL patterns not being read

Tags: python, django

So I am following a Django tutorial and I have reached the stage where I add my own URL patterns to the urls.py file.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url((r'^webapp/', include('webapp.urls'))),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

the problem is that when I run the server Django doesnt even search for the pattern. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

webapp.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

Comment: Is there currently content in `webapp.urls` that Django can understand? Also why the extra set of parentheses?

Comment: What is the full path to the file you posted above?

Comment: And Remove the extra () in the first url.

Comment: @souldeux I fixed the parentheses but the issue persists. Also updated the question with the contents of webapp.urls

Comment: Just to be sure - did you create webapp with python manage.py startapp webapp?

Comment: @sahutchi yes i did use the python manage.py startapp webapp command

Comment: Did you add `webapp` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @Nifled I did, its at the top of my list

Comment: I have a feeling it may be an environment error but I'm not sure what to do nor what is actually wrong

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the directory structure is:

```
app
   app
      urls.py
   webapp
      urls.py
```

You write about a file named `webapp.urls.py` that is unusable by django

Answer (score 0):

You pass wrong arguments for `url()`.

Wrong:

```
url((r'^webapp/', include('webapp.urls')))
```

Right:

```
url(r'^webapp/', include('webapp.urls'))
```